# Info on SSH tunelling etc in certain context

Tags: ssh-tunnel, tunneling, host

Im an electronics engineer, with very little knowledge of networking and assoc. terminology

I recently got a [Lantronix XPort Pro](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport-pro.html) for use in a project I am working on but have little to no knowledge of the concepts involve in setting this up for use.

Have been able to muddle through getting it connected to my laptop but I need to be able to set it up to connect to it by SSH and send a string of data "through" it and out on its  serial connection.

Have been getting myself very confused with the [user guide](http://www.lantronix.com/support/downloads/?p=XPORTPRO) provided, what with hosts, tunnels, lines, accept or connect modes etc

Most articles online seem to address these concepts from the angle of home networks, or as if I already knew what I was talking about! can anyone recommend any good resources for understanding these things that doesn't rely on me already knowing a lot about networking?

Lantronix forum requires manual moderator confirmation which takes time, else I would be asking there :)

Thanks

Comment: Just read faq's that recommend against this type of question, but TBH I dont see another SE site that it fits on... any mod that thinks otherwise I would be delighted to have it moved to a more fitting location :)     (maybe Super User?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptual introduction to SSH : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell

TLS (newer name for the SSL family of technology)[included because the box supports SSL which may be a reasonable alternative depending on your application]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer

Given a bit more information on the application I can give you a richer response.

Comment: wrote a big long reply, then realised what I really need is to get talking to the Lantronix guys as they are the folks that are going to have the answers to this on hand. I'll just have to wait on that forum confirmation. Thanks for your reply though.